# How to login to a website with a Java Login applet using c#

Tags: c#, java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, authentication

I have a website that I administrate and in the future, the updates to the website need to be automated from another data source.

This is not usually a problem (I have done similar using Internet Explorer before and read information from the websites perfectly). Having a username and password login is not usually a problem, as you can usually poke these into the right input controls on the web page.

However, this one is different.

The only place on the whole website where they use a Java Applet is for the Username and password and all I can see is the applet.

What is weird is that if i try to interact with the website with Chrome, it just shows me the normal Username and password controls. Why might the website not use the applet for Chrome, but use the applet for IE? If Chrome does work better and gets around the applet login issue, does anyone know what object I can use to manipulate Chrome?

I am still researching this at the moment to see if this is practical and this is why I am asking these questions.

Any useful suggestions are welcome.